# Does JMeter interact with physical browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I have customer's report that the upload file function on our web application doesn't work sometimes. We tested in house and it does't happen. So I used JMeter to perform Performance Test on the web application (simulating 1000 users to upload at the same time). My Manager said the Graph Resutls, as well as Summary Report from JMeter don't help much in this case to detect where the problem could be. He asks if JMeter can actually upload on the UI and we can see what happening.

As far as I know, JMeter is an Emulator after all, it couldn't interact with web browser the way Selenium WebDriver does (?!). Is there anyway to do Performace test of Upload button and we can actually see it on the WepApp? I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: jmeter can run selenium users too, but your manager is confused (re: "can actually upload on the UI"). File upload does not happen on UI - it's impossible. It happens on HTTP level, which is what JMeter simulates. What happens "on UI level" is execution of JavaScript that creates HTTP request (even that is not quite UI). o if suspicion is that client side (JS) does not work - it's one direction, and you can use normal Selenium tests for that. If suspicion is about the load, then HTTP level on JMeter should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render responses. JMeter can execute HTTP requests via its [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler so from the backend server point of view there is no difference whether file upload is being made by real browser or by JMeter.

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article to learn how to properly configure JMeter so your test would be more realistic.

---

With regards to [Graph Result](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results) and [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) - I don't think they tell the full story. I would suggest going for the following approach:

1. Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to the file upload request which will explicitly check for upload success
2. Start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until errors start occurring.
3. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and see how increasing load correlates with other metrics (response time, hits per second, errors per second, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add WebDriver to JMeter in order to interact with a fully rendered webpage.

> Web Driver Sampler automates the execution and collection of
>   Performance metrics on the Browser (client-side). A large part of
>   performance testing, up to this point, has been on the server side of
>   things. However, with the advancement of technology, HTML5, JS and CSS
>   improvements, more and more logic and behaviour have been pushed down
>   to the client. This adds to the overall perceived performance of
>   website/webapp, but this metric is not available in JMeter. Things
>   that add to the overall browser execution time may include:
>
> Client-side Javascript execution - eg. AJAX, JS templates CSS
>   transforms - eg. 3D matrix transforms, animations 3rd party plugins -
>   eg. Facebook like, Double click ads, site analytics, etc All these
>   things add to the overall browser execution time, and this project
>   aims to measure the time it takes to complete rendering all this
>   content.

For example, you can add this Javascript code to the Script section in order to navigate to Google.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Official guide: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/